# i18next package is not working with vite app

Tags: reactjs, vite, i18next, react-i18next

I work on vite/react project and I have installed i18next package to handle translation, but the translation is not appearing instead the key of translation appears instead.
Here is mt 18n.js file located in src dir:

```
import i18n from 'i18next'
import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend'
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector'
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next'

i18n
  .use(Backend)
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    backend: {
      loadPath: '/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
    },

    lng: localStorage.getItem('i18nextLng') || 'en',
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    whitelist: ['en', 'ar'],

    react: {
      wait: true,
    },
  })

export default i18n
```

and here is my main.jsx file form wrapping the 18n as provider:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import App from './App.jsx'
import './index.css'
import i18n from './i18n.js'
import { I18nextProvider } from 'react-i18next'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <React.Suspense fallback='loading...'>
    <Router>
    <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
        <App />
    </ I18nextProvider>
    </Router>
    </React.Suspense>
  </React.StrictMode>,
)
```

I have my translation.json files located in public/locales/en/translation.json

which contains the translation as followins:

```
{
    "heroTitle": "Welcome to My Website",
    "heroSubTitle": "Find everything you need"
}
```

and the following is my code in the component that I am working on:

```
function Hero() {
    const { t } = useTranslation()
  return (
    <div>
        <h1>{t("heroTitle")}</h1>
        <h3>{t("heroSubTitle")}</h3>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Hero
```

when I run the app the following text appears:

```
heroTitle
heroSubTitle
```

how to make the values appear instead?

Comment: Is your loadPath correct here? That load path assumes that the `locales` directory is at the same level as main.jsx. Is it nested or at another level in the `public` directory? I.e is it following this structure: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-http-backend/tree/master/example/fallback

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the `i18n` fails to recognize the given `key` (e.g., `heroTitle`), it would display the `key` instead as a last resort - which is good news as it indicates that the `react-i18next` module is functioning properly

In your case, the only problem is that you have set the `loadPath` incorrectly, as @Malcolm mentioned. Let's take a closer inspection on your `loadPath`:

```
loadPath: '/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
```

Using `en` as an example, the `loadPath` is set with an absolute path, it implies that it would load the translation files at `http://localhost:8080/locales/en/translation.json` (assuming the port is `8080`), instead of `http://localhost:8080/public/locales/en/translation.json`.

You would want to change the above settings into either two paths:

1. Using absolute path:

```
loadPath: '/public/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
```

2. Using relative path:

```
loadPath: '../public/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
```

The above two solutions should help.